# fetch array from a given url in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a url.. eg `http://www.example.com/index.php?rou=feed/web_api/categories&key=4&parent=0&level=10`

when i hit the link simply on browser it displays a long list of multidimensional array.

I want to know that is it possible to store the url in a variable, something like this

```
$link=http://www.example.com/index.php?rou=feed/web_api/categories&key=4&parent=0&level=10
```

And then display the array in it as

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($link);
echo '</pre>';
```

and then fetch the values from the array

I tried doing so but it displayed only a blank screen. Not sure if i am going on the right track. can anyone guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for one of these:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/data.php');
```

This will fetch the raw data from the specified URL, and store the contents to the variable.

You may then need to implement your own code to actually parse the raw data, depending on your encoding type.